# Cannot get shared_contexts to work in rspec 3.9.0 / rspec-rails 4

Tags: rspec, rspec2

In previous versions of rspec, I could do something like:

## spec/models/test_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'something', :foobar do
  it 'does not seem to be working' do
    puts lol
  end
end
```

## spec/support/foobar.rb

```
shared_context 'foobar', :foobar do
  let(:lol) { 'haha' }
end
```

## spec/rails_helper.rb

```
...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
end
```

This would work fine, my specs would have access to whatever methods/lets were defined in the shared context... However, when upgrading to rspec-rails 4, this now results in:

```
 Failure/Error: puts lol

 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `lol' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::...
```

Rspec's latest documentation says:

> We've also added a config option that lets you determine how shared
>   context metadata is treated:
>
> RSpec.configure do |config|   config.shared_context_metadata_behavior
>   = :trigger_inclusion   # or   config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups end The former value (:trigger_inclusion) is the default and exists only for backwards compatibility. It treats
>   metadata passed to RSpec.shared_context exactly how it was treated in
>   RSpec 3.4 and before: it triggers inclusion in groups with matching
>   metadata. We plan to remove support for it in RSpec 4.
>
> The latter value (:apply_to_host_groups) opts-in to the new behavior.
>   Instead of triggering inclusion in groups with matching metadata, it
>   applies the metadata to host groups. For example, you could focus on
>   all groups that use the DB by tagging your shared context:
>
> RSpec.shared_context "DB support", :focus do   # ... end

However, after reading that over 5 times, I still have no idea what "apply_to_host_groups" actually means.  What is a `host group` ??? Regardless, setting that configuration option doesn't fix this problem.

I have verified my file in spec/support is being loaded, but for whatever reason, lets/methods defined are not available in the example group using the shared context metadata tag.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the correct syntax.

In your config file:

```rb
  config.include_context 'with that context', type: :foobar
```

Your test:

```rb
describe 'something', type: :foobar do
  it 'does not seem to be working' do
    puts lol
  end
end
```

Your shared tests:

```rb
RSpec.shared_context 'with that context' do
  # Tests go here
end
```

Comment: So there is no way to get shared contexts by tagging an example group with metadata anymore?

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.